# factory function in Laravel won't work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I am fairly new to Laravel. I am trying to seed my database using model factories, but during testing my factory the factory function is complaining an error.

[image]

User Model

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'remember_token',
        'ip_address',
        'active',
        'deleted_at',
    ];

}
```

The Factory

```
$factory->define('App\User', function ($faker) {
    return [

        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => $faker->word,
        'remember_token' => $faker->word,
        'ip_address' => $faker->streetAddress,
        'active' => $faker->randomElement($array = array('',null)),
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now'),
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now'),
        'deleted_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now'),

    ];
});
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to seed only few fields like only name, email and  password

Comment: what class is `$factory`?

Comment: @Luceos it is on the ModelFactory.php file.

Comment: what is the error when you use `php artisan tinker -vvv` it will give you a longer backtrace

Answer (score 0):

have you got these lines in your User model?

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
```

actually would be nice to see the full files starting with `<?php`

Comment: Yes I think the wrong line of code is the use SoftDeletes; BTW it is already been solved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Add Faker just before to $faker

```
$factory->define('App\User', function (Faker $faker) {
    return [

        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->safeEmail,
        'password' => $faker->word,
        'remember_token' => $faker->word,
        'ip_address' => $faker->streetAddress,
        'active' => $faker->randomElement($array = array('',null)),
        'created_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now'),
        'updated_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now'),
        'deleted_at' => $faker->dateTime($max = 'now'),

    ];
});
```